# How to prevent users from deleting files from a folder by csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom, item-level-permissions

this is the code i was using:

```
var subfolderpermission = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
subfolderpermission.Add(clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Contributor));
subAgreements.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(newgroup,subfolderpermission);
```

I want to change that permission from contributor to one which allow the user to upload and view files but no delete possible.